# Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppleIncRootCertificate", withExtension: "cer") == nil

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, pkcs#7, receipt-validation

In order to set up Receipt-Validation in a `Swift` iOS app (using `In-App-Purchase`), I am following this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/9257-in-app-purchases-receipt-validation-tutorial and reading here: *Validating Apple Signed the Receipt*.

Here is a problem I have at this point.

In the code I have this:

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppleIncRootCertificate", withExtension: "cer")
```

And when I check its value, it is nil. Since it is supposed to be used to extract further information, it shoud obviously not be nil. The question is: **what could be wrong in the code or in some setting to make this nil?**

This is my first time to implement Receipt-Validation, so it may well be that I am missing something basic.

Comment: Check this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1411540-url 

Return value of this method can be the file URL for the resource file or nil if the file could not be located.

Comment: OK. I thought I was supposed to get that when calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest().
I am a bit lost. If not, what can I do to get this file?

Comment: It is `nil` because the file AppleIncRootCertificate.cer is not added to your target

Comment: Well, since I don't find it on my computer, I suppose I should get it from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/. Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

I think you probably solved your issue, but this may be useful for someone else on how clearly solve the issue. So, if

`Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppleIncRootCertificate", withExtension: "cer")`

gives you `nil`, you don't have this certificate. As suggested in comments above, go [here](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) and download needed certificate unde the Apple Root Certificates -> Apple Inc. Root Certificate.

Now you need to add downloaded certificate to your target. Move to Build Phases of your target, expand Copy Bundle Resources and press "+" button. Then select "Open Other..." and select certificate. Check the box "import if needed" or something like that and launch an app. Now you shouldn't get nil.

Comment: Thank you, very useful still in 2020!